# How to seprate words into two lines in one cell?

Tags: tables

The table is too wide, and I want to make it narrower by wrapping the `Second` under the `First`, how should I achieve this?

The latex code looks like this currently:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Case Study} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{IBEA} \bigstrut\\
\cline{3-5}        &     & FD & P & U \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{First Second} & Run (c.) & 6090 & 6605 & 7976\bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 6665 & 6187 & 6609 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 39332 & 46001 & 46765 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{First Second} & Run (c.) & 4418 & 4459 & 4513 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4480 & 4384 & 443 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 21081 & 21897 & 21613\bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{First Second} & Run (c.) & 4163 & 4251 & 4282 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4241 & 4186 & 4302\bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 1217 & 1456 & 2524 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
```

[image]

Comment: This is no different than your other question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, this can be achieved by a nested table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut}

% The optional argument specifies the horizontal alignment:
% l = left aligned
% c = centered
% r = right aligned
\newcommand*{\tab}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}%
    #2%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\tab{Case\\Study}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{IBEA} \bigstrut\\
\cline{3-5}        &     & FD & P & U \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\tab{First\\Second}} & Run (c.) & 6090 & 6605 & 7976\bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 6665 & 6187 & 6609 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 39332 & 46001 & 46765 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\tab{First\\Second}} & Run (c.) & 4418 & 4459 & 4513 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4480 & 4384 & 443 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 21081 & 21897 & 21613\bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\tab{First\\Second}} & Run (c.) & 4163 & 4251 & 4282 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4241 & 4186 & 4302\bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 1217 & 1456 & 2524 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: thanks, can "First Second" be in the centre of the cell?

Comment: @sweetyBaby Change `\newcommand*{\tab}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}` to `\newcommand*{\tab}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I just put the column entries that needed stacking into stacks.  The stack alignment is controlled with an optional argument to the stack: `[l]`, `[c]`, or `[r]`.  Also, I set the vertical stacking gap in the preamble with `\setstackgap{S}{length}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, bigstrut}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\Shortunderstack{Case Study}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{IBEA} \bigstrut\\
\cline{3-5}        &     & FD & P & U \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\Shortunderstack{First Second}} & Run (c.) & 6090 & 6605 & 7976\bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 6665 & 6187 & 6609 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 39332 & 46001 & 46765 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\Shortunderstack{First Second}} & Run (c.) & 4418 & 4459 & 4513 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4480 & 4384 & 443 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 21081 & 21897 & 21613\bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\Shortunderstack{First Second}} & Run (c.) & 4163 & 4251 & 4282 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4241 & 4186 & 4302\bigstrut\\
\cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 1217 & 1456 & 2524 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `makecell` package: its aim is specifically to allow multine cells and it has  a  `\multirowcell`command with a syntax slightly different from that of `\multirow`. I also suggest to replace the `bigstrut` package with ``cellspace`; this package allows to define a minimal distance between the top of a row and the bottom of the row above (`\cellspacetoplimit`) and symmetrically a`\cellspacebottomlimit`. In order to make this setting effective, one has to prefix the alignment parameter of the columns with the letter S. It works in math mode with the`math` option.

```
        \documentclass{article}

        \usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, bigstrut}
        \usepackage{cellspace} 
      \cellspacetoplimit = 4pt
       \cellspacebottomlimit  = 4pt

        \begin{document}

      \begin{table*}[t]
        \centering
        \caption{Add caption}
        \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Case Study} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{5} & \multicolumn{3}{Sc|}{IBEA} \\%
    \cline{3-5}        &     & FD & P & U \\%
        \hline
        \multirowcell{3}[-4pt]{First \\[6pt] Second} & Run (c.) & 6090 & 6605 & 7976 \\%
    \cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 6665 & 6187 & 6609 \\%\
    \cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 39332 & 46001 & 46765 \\%
        \hline
        \multirowcell{3}[-4pt]{First \\[6pt] Second} & Run (c.) & 4418 & 4459 & 4513 \\%
    \cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4480 & 4384 & 443 \\%
    \cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 21081 & 21897 & 21613 \\%
        \hline
        \multirowcell{3}[-4pt]{First \\[6pt] Second} & Run (c.) & 4163 & 4251 & 4282 \\%
    \cline{2-5}        & Run (nc.) & 4241 & 4186 & 4302 \\%
    \cline{2-5}        & \#Missed & 1217 & 1456 & 2524 \\%
        \hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \label{tab:addlabel}%
        \end{table*}%

        \end{document}
```

[image]